# How to handle purchase made outside of the app (From Google play store)

Tags: android, notifications, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

Recently Google adds the option to resubscribe the in-app subscription from the google play store even when the plan expired (up to one year). You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#resubscribe-before)

When the user re-purchased the subscription from the google play store, we got the callback in the back-end server using the real-time notification system while calling the purchased API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions)  we never get the obfuscatedAccountId that was set while purchasing the first time subscriptions.

Is there any way to map the userid in the subscriptions while resubscribing so that I get to know which user has invoked the resubscribe of the subscription.

Comment: how is the problem solved ?